# What is the default WindowProc of a list-view control?

Tags: c, winapi, listview

What is the default WindowProc of a list-view control before I change it using `SetWindowLong()`?

Comment: The value you get when you call GetWindowLongPtr() first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's determined by the system when it registers the window class. It is presumably implemented in comctl32.

There's nothing special about one of the built-in window classes in this regard. Just as is the case for a user defined class, the default window proc is whatever was specified when the class was registered.

Answer (score 1):

to get the wndproc for a window class use GetClassLongPtr with nIndex=GCLP_WNDPROC, also you can use SetClassLongPtr to super class the window.